# Joining table against two rows to find jar containing both Snickers and Mars?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a database table called `jars`, and another one called `sweets`. Sweets go inside jars so each sweet row has a `jarid` column which stores the id of the jar containing the sweet. Users own jars they've created.

This is my table `sweets`:

```
id | userid | jarid | title
---+--------+-------+---------
1  | 1      | 1     | snickers
2  | 1      | 1     | mars
3  | 2      | 2     | snickers
4  | 2      | 2     | mars
```

Is there an easy way to find jars that contains both at least one snickers and at least one mars, and are also owned by a specific user? I thought of doing a join but I want to match on the condition of the contents of two rows, not one.

Comment: I dont understand this part: "under both specified `X` userid **and** any specified jarid" If you specify a jarid, then you will get zero or one row, since only one jar can have any jarid.

Comment: @Anders The aim of the code is to find jars which both contain snickers and mars which belong to the currently logged in user. The whole point of the code and sql is to find an appropriate `jarid`. Finding zero or one row is the desired goal.

Comment: Do you want to check if a a specific jar has both a snickers and a mars? So you already have a jarid?

Comment: The table in the question, is it `sweets`, `jars` or a combination of them? Could you give us the structure of both tables? And perhaps also the users tables?

Comment: @Anders The sweets, snickers and mars analogy was just analogy. I'm not using those terms for my website. On my site there's a `rooms` table for chat rooms and a `roommembers` table which lists the users chatting in the `room`. `roommembers and rooms is to sweets and jars`. Rooms hold up to 4 people and `roommembers` lists the members of the room. However, some users will want to contact the admin of the site (me), so I need to check `roommembers` for **two** rows at once. One which both contains the user id of the admin user who replies one-on-one and the logged in user.

Comment: @Anders Once I have found a match looking for **two** rows at once, I then retreive the `roomid` of one of the rows, to find out the `roomid` of the chat room/conversation it's time to load. That way, if a conversation already exists, there'll be no need to create a new one. So in the example of my question, I look for **two** rows at once, snickers and mars and it must match with the logged in `userid` (eg. 1), then once it finds a match, it just gets the `roomid`, which in this case is `jarid`. Then it loads the relevant jar or chat room on the page. Do you get it now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94135/discussion-between-anders-and-desbest).

Comment: The data set is hardly representative of the problem, is it? This is unfortunate as it's led you believe that an incorrect solution below works.

Comment: @Strawberry What solution is incorecct? I encourage you to comment on that answer so it can be improved.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an IN clause to look for rows with either snickers or mars. The key here is to use a GROUP BY/HAVING clause along with a COUNT DISTINCT to make sure the jar contains *both* snickers and mars.

```
SELECT userid, jarid
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE title IN ('mars', 'snickers')
    GROUP BY userid, jarid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT title) = 2; /* 2 because there are 2 distinct elements in the IN clause */
```

Comment: @desbest This is the standard solution

Answer (score 1):

I think this should solve it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.jarid         -- The DISTINCT keyword gives you only unique rows.
FROM sweets AS a, sweets AS b   -- Use two versions of the table.
WHERE                           -- Make sure that...
  a.jarid = b.jarid AND         -- they both have the same id,
  a.title = "mars" AND          -- one contains a mars,
  b.title = "snickers" AND      -- one contains a snickers,
  a.userid = :user              -- and the jar belongs to the right user.
```

Answer (score -2):

The conditions you have are not on the join but on the rows of the indvidual tables. Put the conditions in the WHERE clause and use an inner join. This will only return rows that satisfy the join condition as well as all the conditions in the WHERE clause. Used the group by part by Joe Stefanellis answer.

```
SELECT * FROM `sweets` 
INNER JOIN jars on `sweets`.`jarid` = `jars`.`id`
WHERE (`sweets`.`title` = 'snickers' OR `sweets`.`title` = 'mars') 
AND `jars`.`userid` IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY  jars.userid, jars.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sweets.title) = 2;
```

Comment: Your old code worked too and it only took 3 lines instead of 4.

Comment: same code, just added a line break before the AND and some quotes. Good to hear it helped!

Comment: Actually your code doesn't work. When also it gives an sql error due to what you wrote for the IN bit and after. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c9a76/4 Run the query then comment out the IN bit afterwards.

Comment: Could the downvoters please let me know what's wrong?

Comment: @desbest I updated your fiddle and added a jar that does not have both sweets, to make sure it's not being returned by my answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a4a800/1/0

Comment: What is wrong with your code is that I'm trying to match **two** rows at once, not one. I am looking for one row with `snickers`, one row with `mars` which both share the same `jarid` and `userid`. The sqlfiddle link you gave me shows me two `mars` in the `title` when there should be one `snickers` and one `mars`.

Comment: You asked "Is there an easy way to find jars that contains both at least one snickers and at least one mars, and are also owned by a specific user?" 
My solution returns those jarids (1 and 2).
I don't understand your new requirement (one mars one snickers).

Comment: I want a SQL query that will find **two** rows, not one, and each row must have the same `userid` and `jarid` but one row must contain `snickers` and the other row must contain `mars` in the `title` column.